# Complex C program

Tags: c, string

C code to generate all strings of length upto k on a given set of symbols. No symbol should be repeated in any string.
Example:
Take the 6 lower-case symbols in the English alphabet {a, b, c, d, e, f} and k = 3; print the first 25 strings of your output sorted in dictionary order.

Can anyone help me out please?

**EDIT**

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h> 


void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}


void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
   int j;
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
       }
   }
} 


int main()
{
   char a[] = "ABC";
   permute(a, 0, 2);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

This however will give the permutations of all the alphabets. Replacing the alphabets to be parametrized by blank space doesn't seem to do the trick!
Even repetedly calling permute with permutable blank spaces doesnt sound efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your pool of characters is sorted and without repetitions (may need some preprocessing), generating the desired strings in lexicographic order is automatic (in the approach I have in mind).

Look at the short example of all nonempty strings that can be generated from "ABC" with the restrictions:

```
A
AB
ABC
AC
ACB
B
BA
BAC
BC
BCA
C
CA
CAB
CB
CBA
```

You need to keep track of

1. How many characters you have chosen, which, and in which order: and `int` and a `char[]`
2. How many characters you may still choose and which: an `int` and a `bool[]` (or `char[]`, `int[]`)
3. How many strings you still need to output, since that will be modified in recursive calls: an `int*`

   void permute(char *pool, int pool_length, int num_picked, char *stringy,
                bool *picked, int max_length, int *strings_left) {

   ```
   int i;
   for(i = 0; *string_left > 0 && i < pool_length; ++i) {
       if (pool[i] may be picked) {
           // 1. pick that as the num_picked + 1st character
           // 2. output and decrement *strings_left
           // 3. recur
           // 4. unpick pool[i]
       }
   }
   ```

   }

I hope that helps and I haven't given too much away.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks like code that will print the permutations of the alphabet, but where's this k represented in your code?  You have no mechanism in place to cause your code to stop recursing after you got to length k.

Also, I think you might have problems when calling printf() in the permute function.  it makes more sense if the permute function returns a string, and then you could printf what it returns.

EDIT:

The basic concept of recursion is to solve a problem, by solving a smaller version of itself.

So let's say your Alphabet is {'A', 'B', 'C'}, what you want to return is:

"A" and then "A" concatinated to all valid return values of {'B', 'C'}
"B" and then "B" concatinated to all valid return values of {'A', 'C'}
"C" and then "C" concatinated to all valid return values of {'A', 'B'}